# MUI - How to get theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight value responsively?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, toolbar

I wonder how to use mui's `theme.mixins.toolbar` to calculate `height: calc(100vh - toolbar)`?

I am currently trying to do

```
function SwipeCard() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: (theme) => `calc(100vh - ${theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight}px)`,
        paddingTop: (theme) => theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight + "px",
      }}
    >
      hello world
    </Box>
  );
}

export default SwipeCard;
```

But when I change viewport size and the toolbar becomes bigger. `Theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight` stays the same at `56` instead of expected `64`?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out you can just add a second empty `Toolbar` to act as the padding for your content if your `main Toolbar position is fixed`. It comes automatically with the same `media queries` as the main `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make this `{...theme.mixins.toolbar}` you will get the minHeight responsively.
So I used this in `Box` component that I placed above to simulate paddingTop.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution for this.
You can create a styled component and specify the minHeight accordingly.

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

export const StyledBoxMaxHeight = styled(Box)({
  "@media (min-width:0px)": {
    "@media (orientation: landscape)": {
      minHeight: `calc(100dvh - 48px)`,
    },
  },
  "@media (min-width:600px)": {
    minHeight: `calc(100dvh - 64px)`,
  },
  minHeight: `calc(100dvh - 56px)`,
});
```

Comment: You can customize this more to access the 48px using the theme object if required